# Home networking - Wireless switch?

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, ethernet, switch

I currently have a Linksys WRT160N that has a couple wireless clients and a few wired clients. We are planning to switch from DSL to cable and unfortunately, there isn't a cable point in a location close to the wired clients (i.e. the new location of the router would be too far from the wired clients to lay Ethernet cables).

Thus, I was wondering if there was a wireless switch of some sort in which it would be a standard Ethernet switch that would connect to my wireless network? (This is a home network,of course.)

Comment: yes, you're looking for an Access Point or Bridge to connect your cable modem (at the new location) to your existing networking equipment.

Comment: Looks like the Wireless Bridging mode in DD-WRT (http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge) was what I was looking for, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!